# Is there a way to move the image itself while dragging it using React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, drag-and-drop

I am creating a project when I drag and drop an image into another image it switches its place.

I need a way to move the image itself while dragging it and it should also replace with the target image(where it is dropped).

```
function MainGroup (){

const intialImg = [
    { id: 1, name: "BOX1", src: Mercury },
    { id: 2, name: "BOX2", src:Venus },
    { id: 3, name: "BOX3", src:Earth },
    { id: 4, name: "BOX4", src:Mars },
    { id: 5, name: "BOX5", src:Jupiter },
    { id: 6, name: "BOX6", src:Saturn },
    { id: 7, name: "BOX7", src:Uranus },
    { id: 8, name: "BOX8", src:Neptune },
    { id: 9, name: "BOX9", src:Pluto },
    { id: 10, name: "BOX10", src:Ast1 },
    { id: 11, name: "BOX11", src:Ast2 },
    { id: 12, name: "BOX12", src:Ast3 },
    { id: 13, name: "BOX13", src:Ast4 },
    { id: 14, name: "BOX14", src:Ast5 },
    { id: 15, name: "BOX15", src:Ast6 },
    { id: 16, name: "BOX16", src:Ast7 }
  ]

  const [images, setImages] = useState([])
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)

  if(images.length === 0)
  {
    setImages(intialImg)
  }

  const handleStart = data => e => {
    if(!data) return;
    let fImg = JSON.stringify({ id: data.id });
    e.dataTransfer.setData("draggedImg", fImg);
  };

   const handleStop = data => e => {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    return false;
  };

  const handleDrop = data => e => {
    e.preventDefault();
  
    let fImg = JSON.parse(e.dataTransfer.getData("draggedImg"));
    let toImg = { id: data.id };
  
    swapImages(fImg, toImg);
    return false;
  };

  const swapImages = (fromImg, toImg) => {
    let tempImg = images;
    let fIndex = -1;
    let tIndex = -1;

    for (let i = 0; i < tempImg.length; i++) {
      if (tempImg[i].id === fromImg.id) {
        fIndex = i;
      }
      if (tempImg[i].id === toImg.id) {
        tIndex = i;
      }
    }

    if (fIndex !== -1 && tIndex !== -1) {
      let { fromId, ...fromRest } = tempImg[fIndex];
      let { toId, ...toRest } = tempImg[tIndex];
      tempImg[fIndex] = { id: fromImg.id, ...toRest };
      tempImg[tIndex] = { id: toImg.id, ...fromRest };

      setImages(tempImg)
      setCounter(counter => counter + 1)
      console.log(images)
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{counter}</h1>
        <div className="boxesGroup" >
          {images.map(image =>
            <img 
              key={image.id} 
              className="box" 
              src={image.src} 
              alt={image.id} 
              onDragStart={handleStart({id: image.id})}
              onDragOver={handleStop({id: image.id})}
              onDrop={handleDrop({id: image.id})} >
            </img>
            )}
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default MainGroup;
```

This is the entire react code which swaps the images on drag and drop.

[image: The image being dragged.]

> The image shows the image being dragged but its ghost preview is only being dragged. I need the image to drag along with the cursor